# Grunt: Automatically adding script tags

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, yeoman

This may be a stupid question, but I'm quite new to using grunt. I've got an application scaffolded out using the angular yeoman generator. In the index.html I notice lines like this:

```
<!-- build:js({.tmp,app}) scripts/scripts.js -->
<script src="scripts/app.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/controllers/main.js"></script>
<!-- endbuild -->
```

Is there a way to to automatically add new script tags as I add files to the scripts directory out of the box, or do I need to use something like `grunt-file-blocks`?

Answer (score 6):

One way to do this is with the `grunt-script-link-tags` plugin, [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-script-link-tags)

Assuming all of your scripts are in the `scripts` directory, you can add this to your *Gruntfile.js*:

```
tags: {
    build: {
        src: [
            'scripts/**/*.js'
        ],
        dest: 'index.html'
    }
}
```

And then add this to your *index.html*:

```
<!-- start auto template tags -->
<!-- end auto template tags -->
```

The result will be all `*.js` files in scripts (and sub-folders) will be inserted into `index.html` in a new `script` tag.